# Order of occurences effect on probabillity.

Tags: probability

I have a question about probabillity:
we have a box with 40 balls and 40 players who randomly select 1 ball each. 15 black and 25 white balls.
Iv'e been asked what is the chance that all of the 15 black balls were taken where the 20th player steps up to make his selection?

I know that the answer is easy: I have 19 occurences of ball selection, I need to sum all of the cases that have 15 black balls selections within these 19. But I noticed since we don't return the chosen balls, the probabilities might vary for each case but I'm not sure about that, and its difficult to calculate.
So is there a formula to calculate such things?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  No black balls will remain available by the time the $20$'th person takes their turn picking a ball if and only if among the first $19$ selections all $15$ black balls are picked and $4$ white balls are picked.  Apply the hypergeometric distribution.  $\dfrac{\binom{15}{15}\binom{25}{4}}{\binom{40}{19}}$

Comment: Thank you sir. Reading about it now.